# Need to call filter method using specific type

Tags: c#, generics, expression

I have the logic below which takes an expression, converts it into a function and filters the list accordingly

```
public async void ProcessCountriesAsync()
{
    var countries = new List<Country>()
    {
        new Country() {Name = "USA"},
        new Country() {Name = "UK"},
        new Country() {Name = "England"},
        new Country() {Name = "Egypt"},
    };
    Expression<Func<Country, bool>> expected = p => p.Name.StartsWith("E") && p.Name.Length > 5;
    var result = FilterCountries(countries, expected);
    return result;
}

private List<Country> FilterCountries(List<Country> list, Expression expression)
{   
    var expressionText = expression.SerializeExpression();
    var function = expressionText.DeserializeExpression<Country>().Compile();
    var result = list.Where(function).AsQueryable().ToList();
    return result;
}
```

This works perfectly and gives me England

However, I now want to make a more generic version of this which I can use as a function

So I created FilterList

```
public static List<T> FilterList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Expression expression)
{
    var expressionText = expression.SerializeExpression();
    var function = expressionText.DeserializeExpression<T>().Compile();
    var result = list.Where(function).AsQueryable().ToList();
    return result;
}
```

In my calling method Process below I need to call FilterList but I cant because of entityType not being valid

```
public static void Process()
{
    var countries = new List<Country>()
    {
        new Country() {Name = "USA"},
        new Country() {Name = "UK"},
        new Country() {Name = "England"},
        new Country() {Name = "Egypt"},
    };
    var entityType = typeof(Country);
    Expression<Func<Country, bool>> expected = p => p.Name.StartsWith("E") && p.Name.Length > 5;
    var filtered = FilterList<entityType>(countries, expected);
}
```

How can I resolve this please?  These methods are in a static class so not sure that I can use reflection

Paul

Comment: You already know the `T` to be used by the FilterList method. when you are passing Expression<Func<T, boo>> to it.... why you need to have explicit `entityType`?

Comment: You are serializing the expression and then deserializing it back.. why you need to all these when you directly do `countries.Where(expected).ToList()`. You don't even need `FilterList` method... what am I missing here?

Comment: I'm with @Chetan here, you seem to be overcomplicating things. You already have `Where`, why do you need to write this method?

Comment: Also the method is particularly unsafe as it takes a plain `Expression`. You'd be far better off passing in `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` instead, which would remove a lot of your pain.

Comment: Finally, what is the point of the call to `AsQueryable`? It seems superfluous.

Comment: I will be removing the call to AsQueryable

Comment: There will be different expressions that are serialized to string which need to be run depending on the type